# How to correct use import when importing neighbor module

Tags: python, import

my projects directory looks that:

```
-project
    -moduleA
        -a.py
        -__init__.py
    -moduleB
        -b.py
        -__init__.py
```

in file a.py I want to import function from b.py, pycharm suggest me to do it in this way

```
#file a.py
from moduleB.b import function
```

then I execute a.py from pycharm evrythinks work, but when I try to do it from command line, python do not see this module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "moduleA\a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from moduleB.b import  function
 ImportError: No module named moduleB.b
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import a module from a relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)

Answer (score 3):

It is because import in a looks for /moduleB but moduleA doesnt have moduleB package in it. My suggestion is put another py file in project import  and call function from there

```
-project
    -moduleA
       -a.py
       -__init__.py
    -moduleB
       -b.py
       -__init__.py
    main.py
```