# How can I permanently add a module to my flask app?

Tags: python, windows, flask, path, environment-variables

yes I know my question sounds like a duplicate but I have tried everything I have found.

I am trying to add a module to my python flask app. This module is located at `../../clients/api` relative to my flask app. I haven't had any problems adding a module before, but for some reason this just doesn't want to work.

So far, I have tried:

1. `sys.path.append("mypath")` (worked temporarily but as soon as the shell was closed it disappeared)
2. adding a `.pth` file in `lib/site-packages`
3. adding it directly to my environment variables
4. adding in in my IDE (Wing 101)

Aside from 1., none of them had any effect whatsoever.

```
$ flask run
 * Serving Flask app "main.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "main", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
__import__(module_name)
  File "my_flask_app_path", line 20, in <module>
from clients.api import Client as client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'
```

Running this on python v-3.7.1, Windows 10, both git bash and cmd. Please try not to be blunt :)

Comment: Can you add the file structure of your project? Did you create a `__init__.py` in `../../clients/api`?

Comment: Can you quote your `import` from the code here?

Comment: @caverac yes I did. File structure is `pipeline/clients/api` and `pipeline/server/main.py`

Comment: @reportgunner currently it is `from pipeline.clients.api import Client as client`, but I have also tried the `..` notation

Comment: I'm afraid what you are trying to do is not possible - importing modules from a "neighboring" or "sibling" directory. see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927127/how-to-correct-use-import-when-importing-neighbor-module) You will have to move your `main.py` one directory higher, i.e. to `pipeline`

Comment: @reportgunner really? Because this is company-wide code, and everyone else's code appears to work. Mine is the only Windows computer here so I assume it is an enviromental issue.

Comment: sorry, not "impossible". you can apparently do it by messing with `sys.path`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40612922/10417531)

Comment: @reportgunner which I have already tried